# Improve the auto message for "This should be an edit to your question" From Review

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts, self-answer, automatic-comments

Not a shower thought, but nearly :

If you review a self-answer in the low-quality queue and select *Recommend Deletion,* you can find this option:

> **This answer should be an edit to the question**

Choosing it will cause this canned comment to be made on the answer:

> Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](http://#) – [Blag](http://#)

I’m proposing to switch the literal `edit` to the special `[edit]` in this auto message, as it’ll provide a direct edit link to the author :

> Please use the [**edit**](http://#) link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](http://#) – [Blag](http://#)

A small change, but as the `[edit]` is *exactly* made for this use, it seem stupid no one already suggested this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I concur with your general idea.

However, unless I am very much mistaken, just changing `edit` to `[edit]` will not work, as the resulting edit link will be for the answer, not the question.

Instead, the system would have to insert the explicit edit link to the question (i.e., something like `http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/288654/edit`). This is probably easy to do since this link is straightforward to generate and the comment has enough room for it.